# JBoss EAP 6 cannot find JARs in APP-INF/lib

Tags: java, jboss, migration, ejb, weblogic

I am doing a migration from Weblogic to JBoss EAP 6.4 but I am having a problem deploying to and starting the JBoss server.

My EAR structure is as follows:

```
.EAR
|
|---APP-INF
|      |---lib
|           |---[many .jar files]
|
|---META-INF
|       |---application.xml
|       |---jboss-deployment-structure.xml
|
|---[EJB JAR files]
```

**The problem:**

The EJB JARs in the root of the EAR cannot access the classes in the JARs that are in the `APP-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: Check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually put the `lib` folder at the root of the EAR instead of in the `APP-INF` folder and it seemed to do the trick.

JBoss was looking inside `.EAR/lib` instead of `.EAR/APP-INF/lib`

Then, I added the following in the `maven-ear-plugin` section in my `pom.xml` to get maven to create the `lib` folder at the root and not in `APP-INF`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate-application-xml</goal>
            <initializeInOrder>true</initializeInOrder>
        </goals>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do you run jboss on windows? I noticed that I can use sub catalogs like `APP-INF/lib` or `my/lib` on mac but it fails on windows. Also tried backslash with no success.

Comment: @Love yes, I did it on Windows

Answer (score 1):

The `APP-INF/lib` location is specific to WebLogic. There are two solutions:

- Make Maven build the app according to standards - `/lib`. That's what you did in your answer.
- Since Java EE 5 you can include the library-directory parameter in your META-INF/application.xml file:

  ```
  <application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">
     <module>
        <ejb>hello-ejb.jar</ejb>
     </module>
     <module>
        <web>
       <web-uri>myapp.war</web-uri>
       <context-root>myapp</context-root>
        </web>
     </module>
     <library-directory>APP-INF/lib</library-directory>
  </application>
  ```

As an alternative, you can include the same parameter in your `jboss-app.xml`:

```
    <application>
      <display-name>My Application</display-name>
      <module>
        <web>
          <web-uri>myapp.war</web-uri>
          <context-root>/myapp</context-root>
        </web>
      </module>

      <module>
        <ejb>myapp.jar</ejb>
      </module>

      <library-directory>APP-INF/lib</library-directory>

    </application>
```